# Finding a recurrence that satisfies a sequence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, recursion

> Consider the sequence:
>
> $1,1,1,3,5,9,17,31,\ldots$
>
> Find both a recurrence and a different sequence that satisfies this recurrence.

Saw a decent pattern until the 31 appeared...Pretty stuck. Any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: Tribonacci numbers. $a_{n+3}=a_{n+2}+a_{n+1}+a_{n}$.

Comment: Did you try http://oeis.org/search?q=+1%2C1%2C1%2C3%2C5%2C9%2C17%2C31&language=english&go=Search ?

Comment: I did not know that website existed. Thank you very much for the reference.

Comment: Why don't you attempt coming up with a Binet formula for these numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1 + 1 + 1 = 3\\1+1+3 = 5\\1+3+5 = 9\\3+5+9 = 17\\5+9+17 = 31$

One *possible* recurrence is given by $a_{n+1} = a_n + a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}$ with $a_0 = a_1 = a_2 = 1$. A good way to see if your sequence is recognised is to search it up on [OEIS](https://oeis.org/). This sequence is listed as [A000213](https://oeis.org/A000213). Note however, that this sequence is not unique. Given a finite amount of elements of a sequence, an infinite amount of formulas can be made to fit those elements (there's two more on OEIS, namely [A074858](https://oeis.org/A074858) and [A074860](https://oeis.org/A074860)).

A different sequence that also fits the sequence in the question is given by $a_n = {n^7 \over 315} -{n^6 \over 12}+ {157 n^5 \over 180}-{55 n^4 \over 12}+{2263 n^3 \over 180}-{49 n^2 \over 3}+ {793 n \over 105}+1$ which is the the [Lagrange Polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) for the given data points.